# Unity game crashes on blue stacks and Note 8

Tags: unity-game-engine, crash

I have a Unity game which was previously working fine on all devices.
We added some more functionality which was not a lot and now it crashes on BlueStacks and one Note8 device that we tested on.

It works fine on other devices.

Here is a link to the log I got from blue stacks.  https://pastebin.pl/view/5243af9d

I'm not sure what is causing the crash. I've tried disabling environment etc too just to make sure it is not a memory issue.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Updating to Unity 2019.4.10 LTS fixed the issue.